# Javascript match for string that doesn't contain a character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use Javascript match a url pattern containing one directory, with an optional trailing slash.

For example

This should match:

> text and http://twitter.com/path and more text

This should not match:

> text and http://twitter.com/path**/other/directories** and more text

Even though the shorter string exists in the longer one, I don't want the longer one to return anything.

Is this possible?

---

Here's what I've tried so far:

The approach was to match the url, and then either use a negative character class, or a negative lookback

I've tried the following:

```
/(https?:)?(\/\/)?(www\.)?twitter\.com\/[a-z0-9_+-]+\/?(?![a-z0-9_+-])/ig
```

This was meant to look for a twitter URL, with a `\w+` path, with optional trailing slash, not followed by any other `\w+`.

While this doesn't include the second directory in its match, I wanted it to not match the string at all.

```
/(https?:)?(\/\/)?(www\.)?twitter\.com\/\w+[^\/\w]*/ig
```

This was meant to find the URL, but exclude slashes and `\w` following. Similar to the previous try, it still matches the long links.

I've tried variations like this, but can't get it to work:

```js
var regex1 = /(https?:)?(\/\/)?(www\.)?twitter\.com\/\w+(?!\/\w+)/ig;

var regex2 = /(https?:)?(\/\/)?(www\.)?twitter\.com\/\w+[^\/\w]*/ig;

var shouldMatch = 'text https://twitter.com/page text';
var shouldNotMatch = 'text https://twitter.com/page/status/123 text';

console.log('regex1 should match', shouldMatch.match(regex1));

console.log('regex1 should return []', shouldNotMatch.match(regex1));

console.log('regex2 should match', shouldMatch.match(regex2));

console.log('regex2 should return []', shouldNotMatch.match(regex2));
```

Comment: Why not just assert end of string? `/(https?:)?(\/\/)?(www\.)?twitter\.com\/\w+\/?$/`

Comment: Thanks @Nick the full strings contain lots of other text, so it wouldn't be the end of a string

Comment: you can add range of characters to handle this scenario. e.g. ([\w\d_-]+\/?)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead at the end of the valid part, asserting that the page name is not followed by either a `/` and a word character, or another word character. The addition of the other word character alternation to the negative lookahead prevents the regex otherwise matching at (for example) `http://twitter.com/pag`.

```js
var regex1 = /(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?twitter\.com\/\w+(?!\/\w|\w)/ig;


var shouldMatch = 'https://twitter.com/page is a valid url';
var shouldNotMatch = 'https://twitter.com/page/status/123 is not valid';

console.log('regex1 should match', shouldMatch.match(regex1));

console.log('regex1 should return []', shouldNotMatch.match(regex1));
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would use positive lookahead to assert that there's either a whitespace character or the end of the string following the last group of `\w+`.

`(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?twitter\.com\/\w+(?=\s|$)`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/EMHxq9/3

I also used non-capturing groups in place of capturing groups because it doesn't look like you're back referencing anything, and combined the optional "https:" and "//" parts because it would be weird to have one and not the other.